# Restrict Cassandra users seeing all keyspaces

Tags: authentication, cassandra, authorization

If I understood correctly, in Cassandra, authenticated users can see the list of all keyspaces. (i.e. full schema)

Is that the default behavior in Cassandra? Can we restrict that behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, when Bhathiya asked the same question on the Cassandra mailing list, it was answered here: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/13b8dyb45d/restrict-cassandra-users-seeing-all-keyspaces.

(TLDR: No, this is by design.)